# imx6 Solox u-boot splash

Tags: yocto, imx6

everyone, 
I would like to change u-boot splash image. Normally, it's showing NXP logo. It's using 4.1.15.2.0 kernel.
How can I change this image and make my own distro? I would appreciate if you help me.

Best regards.

Comment: You want to change the Kernel Splash Image or the U-Boot splash image?

Comment: https://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/UBootSplashScreen

Comment: I mean the u-boot splash image, sorry I'm new in yocto, did only nxp kernel user guide steps and created wayland image with qt. I don't know where to find the u-boot folder and change this image.

Answer (score 1):

You want to enable the u-Boot splash in your boards configuration file:

```
#define CONFIG_SPLASH_SCREEN
```

Then the splash screen will display what is stored in the u-Boot environment variable: `splashimage`

When creating your bitmap image remember to ensure that it matches the colour depth and size.

Taken from u-Boot documentation:

> Since loading an image will define a new color map, the
>   remainder of the display will appear with incorrect colors. It is
>   therefore recommended that all images match exactly the size of the
>   current display device. We accepted these restrictions since speed was
>   top priority, and all attempts to implement scaling or optimizing the
>   color maps would slow down the display too much. It is much easier to
>   perform the necessary transformations on the development host, where a
>   plethora of tools is available.